# Instant film for a 4x5 large format camera?

Tags: film, large-format, polaroid, instant-camera

I have a 4x5 camera and a Polaroid 545 film holder.

Can someone tell me if any kind of instant film (Polaroid or any other brand) compatible with the 545 film holder is still produced today and where it can be purchased?

If not, are there any other alternatives to shoot instant film on a 4x5 today?

I don't want to purchase film that's expired since many years at the sometimes outrageous prices that can be found online...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That fact that expired film sells at outrageous prices should tell you all that you need to know.

Comment: I know of one recent kickstarter project that aims at producing instant film called *ONE INSTANT* which is currently in pre-order, supposedly shipping during this summer (2019). But at € 28 for 3 sheets, it sounds at least as outrageous as buying expired film online... Polaroid still produces 8x10 instant film (at around € 18 per sheet which is even more expensive...). I wonder why they don't produce 4x5 anymore though.

Comment: Be aware of different companies using the Polaroid brand name. The Polaroid Corporation stopped producing instant film products in 2008. At that time, an independent company called the Impossible Project started to produce materials for Polaroid cameras, including 8x10 film, but not 4x5. In 2017, Impossible acquired the brand and intellectual property of the original Polaroid Corporation, and the Impossible Project was renamed Polaroid Originals. But keep in mind that Polaroid Originals is not actually the Polaroid Corporation.

Comment: Damn i miss type 55, it produced an instant print and a negative.

Comment: @MrUpsidown the film market is very small today. The instant film market is even smaller. PO is a small company, and we should be glad they produce 8x10" film in the first place. Their sx-70 film production is already smaller than their 600 film production, because of the limited orders for sx-70 film. Their 8x10" film is all (sporadically) made by hand(!). 4x5" is out of the question. Perhaps 3.25x4.25" is in the picture, because of the large availability of cameras for that film, but [evidently](https://bit.ly/2UFbXzn) peel-apart is just a harsh market.

Comment: @Mick agreed, although that didn't give me a firm answer about my question. Proof is the kickstarter project that I linked to earlier.

Comment: @MrUpsidown "Proof". New55 preceeds ONE INSTANT. The problem with peel-apart film is that it has died, and therefore a revival is hard. The market is incredibly small. The upfront costs are hight, as machines are barely available, or too pricey. Fuji does not want to cooperate, so formulas will have to be developed from the ground up. All the work done is by hand, which makes the film too expensive to buy, and hard to sell. As of now, pack film does not fair well and PO should think long and hard about gambling with it. Other than ONE INSTANT being Kaps', I have not too much confidence in it.

Comment: I must add to my previous comment that New55 produced 4x5" film. ONE INSTANT has taken upon themselves the production of 3.25x4.25" film (type 100), which fits in the commonly available type 100 Land camera. Take the Land 350 for example. I would assume this to have larger potential because of my previous argument.

Comment: I know about that company you mentioned and I know it has died by now. I am having a hard time figuring out what point you're trying to make in your comments... I know it must be hard for any (new) company to bring back that kind of product to the market. All I was asking about was: "Is there anything existing that I am not aware of". And apparently the answer is no.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not! Unless you got plans :)

Answer (score 1):

New55 are still going after a short break, and you can buy new peel apart 4x5 film with both a positive and negative here http://famousformat.com/

As above OneInstant make the smaller peel apart film.

Comment: A short break of about 2 years. At $75 for 5 sheets + $22 shipping (to EU) that's a whopping $19 / sheet. And the PN100 is sold out. But ok thanks.

Comment: Theyve been back up and running for a while. But you;re right it's not cheap. But it's fresh... I have been stung a lot with expired polaroid 4x5 on ebay. I haven't bought a lot of this but hope to try some of the 400 iso this year.

Answer (score 0):

545 did have an instant film, manufactured by Polariod, Camerapedia tells me it was in production till circa 2005. But there's nothing new you can purchase.

If anything I'd try messing with other 4x5in (9x12cm) films in a darkroom, trying to fit. Scissors, spare paper, tape & glue... at least in theory it might work.

Answer (score -1):

I think Fuji still makes pack film.  FPC100-C color film.

Comment: Fuji did its last shipments of FP-100C in 2016.  Stock's still available in some places, but it's not cheap.  The only instant film they make now is Instax.